# MonoTouch CorePlot (using Miguel's sample)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, core-plot

I am using the MonoTouch 4.0.3 framework and having trouble loading and linking the library on to the device for the provided example code for the CorePlot API. It seems to run and work fine in the simulator (it auto-generates the values

`[-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lCorePlotSim -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libCorePlotSim.a"]`

in the additional mtouch arguments field), but crashes on the device as soon as I select the navigation button to load the graph.

Any ideas on how to get the sample code to work on the device? What I need to do to get the `libCorePlotDevice.a` or `libCorePlotSim.a` libraries on the device and linked in correctly?

Thanks,

~Chris

Answer (score 0):

Based on their names, the options you've describing will only work for the simulator. Try replacing **CorePlotSim** for **CorePlotDevice**, e.g.:

```
-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lCorePlotDevice -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libCorePlotDevice.a"
```

You might also want to update your code since Miguel's released newer bindings for CorePlot (0.4) last week.